# How to constrain some columns to be all zeros in pulp

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I'm working on a linear-programming problem with module PulP.

In this problem, we have a (i x j)matrix--A. The objective function is to minimize the production between A and another (j x i)matrix--B. A is the target we want to minimize, B is a constant matrix.

My problem is how to constrain **n** of **j** columns in matrix A being all zeros. n<=j and it is set by user.

**prob** is my LpProblem and **test** is the matrix-A, **pri** is matrix-B.
I know how to create constraint that sum of each row must be 1.

```py
for i in range(pri.shape[1]):
    prob+=lpSum(test[i,:])==1
```

Following code is how I try to make the constraint **n** of **j** columns in matrix A being all zeros. While, it failed and just create a dummy variable I can't understand reason.

```py
count=0
for i in range(pri.shape[0]):
    if lpSum(test[:,i])==0:
        count +=1
prob += count==n

prob.solve()
for v in prob.variables():
    print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)
```

Output:

```
__dummy = None
a_(1,_1) = 1.0
a_(1,_2) = 0.0
a_(2,_1) = 1.0
a_(2,_2) = 0.0
a_(3,_1) = 1.0
a_(3,_2) = 0.0
```

Pulp is not so popular online. I can't find sample code related to my problem. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I think you are confusing data with decision variables. I would suggest to first write down a mathematical model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a binary variable for each column which takes on a value of 1 if that column is used at all, and zero otherwise. This can be done by setting a constraint for each column `j` like follows:

```
lpSum([test[i, j] for i in set_I]) <= M*binary[j]
```

Where `M` is a constant chosen large enough that this constraint will have no effect when the binary value is set to `1`.

You then need 1 more constraint that the number of included columns is not greater than `n`:

```
prob += lpSum([binary[j] for j in set_J]) <= n
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! You answer clearly and it solves my problem.